# Can not compile hello word program of Swift

Tags: swift, compilation, zsh

I was going to use Swift/t and normally I started to with HELLO WORLD code from the gallery. Unfortunately, I encountered compiling error as follow:

> zsh: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

May you please provide me some hints that may help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of errors (`bash/zsh: error while loading shared libraries: ...`) appear when you don't have a library installed on your system.

In your case, your missing library is `libtinfo`, on its version 5. You should be able to search and install it throught your system's package manager.

Just as an example, in Ubuntu you can install it by:

```
sudo apt install libtinfo5
```